# Get random friends from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

There where 2 mysql tables users(id,name,city) and friend_list(id,userid,friend,status).

Now i need to get three random friends from the friend_list table and their name from users table.

```
Friend_list table
id |  userid  |friend |status
1  |    1     |   2   | friends
2  |    3     |   1   | friends
3  |    2     |   3   | friends

users table:
id  |  name
1   | xxx
2   | yyy
3   | zzz
```

I need query something like this.

```
SELECT f.*,u.name FROM friend_list f,users u WHERE (f.userid = 1 or f.friend = 1) AND f.status = 'friends' AND f.userid = u.id AND f.order by RAND() limit 3
```

but for eg: it should select 1 in userid column and also from friend column.

I m trying to achieve it without using JOIN's

Comment: Have you tried using rand() function and join ??

Comment: @rockieB :I used SELECT f.*,u.name FROM friend_list f,users u WHERE (f.userid = 1 or f.friend = 1) AND f.status = 'friends' AND f.userid  = u.id  AND f.order by RAND() limit 3 ` but the problem is that selecting the name from users table. How to match selected row to id column of users table(f.userid  = u.id) and (f.friend = u.id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select 2 random entries try:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT * from users join on Friend_list.userid = users.id where users.id = ?
) as sub_equity
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

I had a same task on a project :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the oreder by rand() as in below  query.

```
select Friend_list.friend,users.name from Friend_list inner join users on Friend_list.userid=users.id order by rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Friend_list.*, users.name
FROM Friend_list INNER JOIN users ON Friend_list.userid = users.id
ORDER BY RAND()  // this will show random records
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```sql
SELECT u.name as person, u2.name as friend_with
FROM users u
INNER JOIN friends_list f ON u.id = f.userid
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = f.friend
WHERE f.userid = 1 or f.friend = 1
AND f.status = 'friends'
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3;
```

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab3a3/8)</kbd>

This will get you three random records with the name of the person and the name of his friend, being one of the userid 1

Comment: I need the result without using join's... See my edit(Added the query close to the result)...

Comment: You have implicit joins in your query. i just used them explicitly. I changed it to add the validation of the userid 1. see if it is what you want

Comment: Will it affect the query processing time if there where more records on table ie. more than 100k or 1000k records...

Comment: Random is not very quick, but it's probably best for you to test it against your data to see if you can use this or if you would have to do attempt a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM friend_list f
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = f.userid
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e483c/1/0

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY RAND()` is quite slow if there are many rows.

If `users.id` is sequential and you have statistic on users.id (e.g. MAX(users.id), MIN(users.id)), generate three random number between min, max in client side.

And following query:

```
SELECT u.name as person, u2.name as friend_with
FROM users u
INNER JOIN friends_list f ON u.id = f.userid
WHERE users.id IN (random_number1, 2, 3);
```

this query can use INDEX, so it's faster than `ORDER BY RAND()`

ah.. users.id would not be continuous (e.g user deleted), so you need to generate enough random number.